# update a timestamp based on the changes happening in another column

Tags: sql, oracle

Given a `source` table that changes overtime, here I will define `source_before` and `source_after` to show the differences happening in the table, but in reality it's the same table

```
create table source_before (
binary_path varchar2(40),
hostname varchar2(40),
change_column varchar2(40),
flag varchar2(20) default 'open'
);

insert all 
into source_before (binary_path,hostname,change_column) values ('python','a','drn') 
into source_before (binary_path,hostname,change_column) values ('java','b','drn') 
into source_before (binary_path,hostname,change_column) values ('apache','c','drn')
into source_before (binary_path,hostname,change_column) values ('spark','d','drn')
select * from dual;


create table source_after (
binary_path varchar2(40),
hostname varchar2(40),
change_column varchar2(40),
flag varchar2(20) default 'open'
);

insert all 
into source_after (binary_path,hostname,change_column) values ('java','b','DMZ') 
into source_after (binary_path,hostname,change_column) values ('apache','c','drn')
into source_after (binary_path,hostname,change_column) values ('NEW','NEW','NEW')
select * from dual;


--- source_before
python  a   open    drn
java    b   open    drn
apache  c   open    drn
spark   d   open    drn

--- source_after
java    b   open    DMZ
apache  c   open    drn
NEW    NEW  open    NEW
```

The primary key is the combination (binary_path,hostname). Now given a destination table where I want to fetch changes that are happening in the source table.

```
create table destination (
binary_path varchar2(40),
hostname varchar2(40),
change_column varchar2(40),
flag varchar2(20),
creation_time timestamp,
open_close_timestamp timestamp
);
```

Initially the table is empty, and the `flag` column should follow this logic:

1. When the primary key combination is detected the first time, the `flag` should `open` which is the default from the `source_*` tables.
2. Whenever the primary key combination disappear from the `source_*` tables the `flag` should `close`.
3. Whenever the primary key combination appears once again from the `source_*` tables  the `flag` which was `close` should `re-open`.

I managed to simulate this behavior with two statements:

```
merge into destination d
using (select * from source_before) s on (d.hostname = s.hostname and d.binary_path = s.binary_path)
when matched then update
set 
d.change_column = s.change_column,
d.flag = 
(
case
when d.flag = 'close' then 're-open' 
else s.flag
end
)
when not matched then insert 
(d.binary_path,d.hostname,d.change_column,d.flag,d.creation_time,d.open_close_timestamp)
values
(s.binary_path,s.hostname,s.change_column,s.flag,current_timestamp,current_timestamp)
;

UPDATE destination d
SET 
flag   = 'close',
open_close_timestamp = current_timestamp
WHERE NOT EXISTS   (SELECT *
                   FROM   source_after s
                   WHERE  s.hostname = d.hostname and
                   d.binary_path = s.binary_path) and flag <> 'close'                   
                   ;
```

I also managed to update the column `open_close_timestamp` to get the latest timestamp when `flag` updates to the `close` state. However I did not manage to update `open_close_timestamp` for the case when the `flag` changes to `open` or `re-open`. The goal is not only to `open` , `re-open` and `close` based on the appearance, re-appearance and disappearance of the combination of primary keys but also to timestamp whenever that modification happens. Note that in order to re-appear the flag can only be `close` in its previous state.

`EDIT`:

As requested I'm explaining better the logic of timestamp:

> The point which I maybe wasn't so clear is that the timestamp should
> only update when the value in the `flag` row switches from one state
> to the other. That is, if the value was before `close`  and we are
> updating with a new value and this value is still `close` then
> timestamp should be the same and not update to the latest current
> time, but if the new value is `open` and before it was close, then we
> should stamp the new time because the state changed.

If I start with `destination` as an empty table and run the code I wrote above it will work once. It will only update the timestamp for the switch of state from rows where before was `open` and after changed to `close`.

```
apache  c   drn open    07-01-2023 08.44.26.479389000 AM    07-01-2023 08.44.26.479389000 AM
spark   d   drn close   07-01-2023 08.44.26.479389000 AM    07-01-2023 08.44.48.451292000 AM
python  a   drn close   07-01-2023 08.44.26.479389000 AM    07-01-2023 08.44.48.451292000 AM
java    b   drn open    07-01-2023 08.44.26.479389000 AM    07-01-2023 08.44.26.479389000 AM
```

The problem is that it will work only once, as I continue to play around with change of state in the flag column, the timestamp will not reflect the changes for changes of state like `close` -> `open` , `open` -> `re-open`.

What allowed me to not change `close` timestamp when before was close, was this section of the code above.

```
 UPDATE destination d
.......
 and flag <> 'close'   <------------- this restriction                  
                       ;
```

I was thinking about a way to make this happen to all changes of state.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the expected output for your sample because it is hard to navigate all the rules and work out what you expect (and why you are bothered about timestamps when you are setting them all to the same value).

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
merge into destination d
using (
    select s.binary_path, s.hostname, s.change_column, s.flag from source s
    union all
    select d.binary_path, d.hostname, d.change_column, 'close' from destination d
    where not exists(select 1 from source s where s.binary_path = d.binary_path and s.hostname = d.hostname)
) s 
on (d.hostname = s.hostname and d.binary_path = s.binary_path)
when matched then update
set 
    d.change_column = s.change_column, 
    d.flag = case when d.flag = 'close' then 're-open' else s.flag end,
    d.open_close_timestamp = case when s.flag = 'close' or d.flag <> 'open' then current_timestamp else d.open_close_timestamp end
when not matched then insert 
(d.binary_path,d.hostname,d.change_column,d.flag,d.creation_time,d.open_close_timestamp)
values
(s.binary_path,s.hostname,s.change_column,s.flag,current_timestamp,current_timestamp)
;
```

Comment: If I run this code several times for `source_after` it will continuously `close` and `re-open` the values that are present in destination and that are not present in `source_after`. It should just stay close and never update the timestamp in that case.

Comment: Just adapt the CASE setting d.flag to your needs, for this 're-open' only if s.flag <> 'close'.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```sql
MERGE INTO destination d
USING source s
ON (d.hostname = s.hostname AND d.binary_path = s.binary_path)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET change_column = COALESCE(s.change_column, d.change_column),
      flag          = CASE
                      WHEN d.flag IN ('open', 'reopen')
                      THEN 'closed'
                      ELSE 'reopen'
                      END,
      open_close_timestamp = SYSTIMESTAMP
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (binary_path,hostname,change_column,flag,creation_time,open_close_timestamp)
  VALUES (s.binary_path,s.hostname,s.change_column,s.flag,SYSTIMESTAMP,SYSTIMESTAMP);
```

If the `source` table contains the `source_before` rows then after the `MERGE` the table contains:

| BINARY_PATH | HOSTNAME | CHANGE_COLUMN | FLAG | CREATION_TIME | OPEN_CLOSE_TIMESTAMP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| python | a | drn | open | 06-JAN-23 19.47.40.123768 | 06-JAN-23 19.47.40.123768 |
| java | b | drn | open | 06-JAN-23 19.47.40.123768 | 06-JAN-23 19.47.40.123768 |
| spark | d | drn | open | 06-JAN-23 19.47.40.123768 | 06-JAN-23 19.47.40.123768 |
| apache | c | drn | open | 06-JAN-23 19.47.40.123768 | 06-JAN-23 19.47.40.123768 |

If the `source` table is then changed to contains the `source_after` rows then the `MERGE` is run again the table will contain:

| BINARY_PATH | HOSTNAME | CHANGE_COLUMN | FLAG | CREATION_TIME | OPEN_CLOSE_TIMESTAMP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| python | a | drn | open | 06-JAN-23 19.47.40.123768 | 06-JAN-23 19.47.40.123768 |
| java | b | DMZ | closed | 06-JAN-23 19.47.40.123768 | 06-JAN-23 19.47.40.190947 |
| spark | d | drn | open | 06-JAN-23 19.47.40.123768 | 06-JAN-23 19.47.40.123768 |
| apache | c | drn | closed | 06-JAN-23 19.47.40.123768 | 06-JAN-23 19.47.40.190947 |
| NEW | NEW | NEW | open | 06-JAN-23 19.47.40.190947 | 06-JAN-23 19.47.40.190947 |

If the `source` table still contains the `source_after` rows then the `MERGE` is run again the table will change to:

| BINARY_PATH | HOSTNAME | CHANGE_COLUMN | FLAG | CREATION_TIME | OPEN_CLOSE_TIMESTAMP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| python | a | drn | open | 06-JAN-23 19.47.40.123768 | 06-JAN-23 19.47.40.123768 |
| java | b | DMZ | reopen | 06-JAN-23 19.47.40.123768 | 06-JAN-23 19.47.40.193350 |
| spark | d | drn | open | 06-JAN-23 19.47.40.123768 | 06-JAN-23 19.47.40.123768 |
| apache | c | drn | reopen | 06-JAN-23 19.47.40.123768 | 06-JAN-23 19.47.40.193350 |
| NEW | NEW | NEW | closed | 06-JAN-23 19.47.40.190947 | 06-JAN-23 19.47.40.193350 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/AB2A2r1h)

Comment: you guessed right on why bothering with timestamps when they are set to same value. The point which I maybe wasn't so clear is that the timestamp should only update when the value in the `flag` row switches from one state to the other. That is, if the value was before `close`  and we are updating with a new value and this value is still `close` then timestamp should be the same and not update to the latest current time, but if the new value is `open` and before it was close, then we should stamp the new time because the state changed.

Comment: @moth This does exactly that and only updates the timestamps when the rows change; you can see that the `python` and `spark` rows do not change their timestamps and that the other rows swap from `open` to `close` to `reopen` and their timestamps change (admittedly the queries are happening so quickly that the changes are in the fractional seconds but you can see the change).